# Pass Array Data to factory from controller in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, slim

Is it possible to pass array data from controller to factory and extract data from factory to slim framework to insert into a database?

```
Array[{}] CONTROLLER -> FACTORY -> SLIM PHP FRAMEWORK -> DATABASE
```

I'am new in AngularJS, can you give me a example? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it on the following way:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope', 'yourFactory', function($scope, yourFactory) {
    $scope.arr; //your array
    yourFactory.sendData($scope.arr).then(function(data) {
        //handle after data is submitted to api/server
    })
}])
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('yourFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        sendData : sendData
    }

    function sendData(arr) {
        $http.post('<api_url>', arr).success(function(response) {
            return response;
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you! It works! :)  but I have a little more problem in php.

Comment: sorry dont know php ;)

Comment: I can't return the number of data in array i use $app = Slim::getInstance();   
 $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
 $post = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
 $data = get_object_vars($post);

 $a = count($post);
 echo json_encode($a);

Comment: try using return instead of echo